# When is a Custom Content Provider called for?

Tags: android

I have seen custom content providers for sqLite in apps, but thats about it. When should a Custom Content provider be built?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[EboMike](https://stackoverflow.com/users/345717/ebomike) in [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4079117/why-should-i-use-custom-content-provider-in-android) says:

- Other apps will be able to access your data.
- You can wrap and abstract a lot of the query logic in your content provider, and limit access.
- You will be able to lean on the system to allow for things like managed queries.

Remember that you can `control user interacts` with your data,for example you can prevent user from modifying data or you can force system to open data with explicit App and so on.